# How to compile ocaml code to native to be used by C++

Tags: c++, ocaml, bytecode, native-code

How can I compile this facebook parser library down to native code so it can be imported by my C++ program
https://github.com/facebook/flow/tree/master/src/parser

I've tried using `ocamlopt` and `dune build` but there seems to be errors.

```
File "src/services/saved_state/dune", line 7, characters 4-29:
7 |     saved_state_dummy_fetcher
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Module Saved_state_dummy_fetcher is excluded but it doesn't exist.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OCaml is a different language from C or C++ and it uses different calling conventions and binary interface (ABI) than C or C++. Nothing special here about OCaml, even code compiled with different C++ compilers, in general, is not compatible and can't be imported.

So, if you want to call a library function written in language A from a program written in the language B you have to use *bindings*. If there are no bindings, then you can write your own, though it is not a trivial project as you have to decide how to translate C data structures to OCaml data structures and vice verse. If you or someone else will decide to pursue this route, here are some tips. The [official documentation](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#s%3Ac-callback) describes the low-level interface. A higher-level and less error-prone interface is provided by the [CTypes](http://ocamllabs.io/ocaml-ctypes/Cstubs_inverted.html) library (which also can generate C code that you can later compile to a .so file).

Of course, before writing stubs you shall also [learn](https://github.com/facebook/flow/tree/master/src/parser#building-the-flow-parser) how to compile the flow project, as the error that you show has nothing to do with importing OCaml code into C or C++ project. You should follow the instructions, provided by the flow [homepage](https://github.com/facebook/flow/).

Comment: If you decide to use ctypes, here is an example of calling OCaml functions from C/C++ https://github.com/yallop/ocaml-ctypes-inverted-stubs-example. Here is the same example if you use Esy as the package manager - https://github.com/prometheansacrifice/esy-inverted-ctypes-stubs